# Error: No module named XXX al ejecutar un script python desde C++

Tags: python, c++

Estoy haciendo un módulo en C++ para python.

Para poder depurar el código C++ mientras ejecuto la parte de python, he hecho un ejecutable mínimo en C++ que se limita a ejecutar un script python:

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <string>

#include <Python.h>

#define MODULE_ROOT "/home/user/workspace"

int main( int argc, const char *argv[] ) {
    if( argc != 2 ) {
        printf( "%s", "Usage: pydebug SCRIPT\n" );
        return 1;
    }

    Py_SetProgramName( (wchar_t*)argv[0] );
    Py_Initialize( );

    // Set the path to find loadable modules.
    {
        std::string command = "import sys\nsys.path.insert( 0, '" MODULE_ROOT "/code/python' )";
        printf( "Set path module:\n%s\n", command.c_str( ) );
        int ret = PyRun_SimpleString( command.c_str( ) );
        printf( "return of import: %d\n", ret );
    }

    std::FILE* fp;

    fp = _Py_fopen( argv[1], "r" );
    PyRun_SimpleFile( fp, argv[1] );
    Py_Finalize( );

    return 0;
}
```

La parte en la que indico la ruta de carga de módulos la he sacado de

[Python Embedding in C++ : ImportError: No module named pyfunction](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24492775/8663418)

El script en python que intento ejecutar, si lo hago a través de la línea de comandos, funciona perfectamente:

```
PYTHONPATH="RUTA_AL_DIRECTORIO_DEL_MODULO" python3 script.py
```

Con lo cual tambien aseguramos que mi módulo compilado, `MiModulo.so` se encuentra en el directorio correcto.

Tengo colocado un `printf( )` para asegurarme de que la ruta que intento indicar (desde C++) es correcta:

```
printf( "Set path module:\n%s\n", command.c_str( ) );
```

> sys.path.insert( 0, '/home/user/workspace/DIRECTORIO_CORRECTO/code/python' )

Y eso coincide con lo que establezco manualmente en la variable de entorno `PYTHONPATH`.

Sin embargo, después de compilar mi ejecutable, al lanzarlo:

```
/home/user/workspace/src/python_wrapper/pydebug script.py
```

> Set path module:
> import sys
> sys.path.insert( 0, '/home/user/workspace/DIRECTORIO_CORRECTO/code/python' )
> return of import: 0
> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "script.py", line 15, in 
> from MiModulo import XXXX, YYYY
> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'MiModulo'

Comment: Un ejemplo de pregunta bien formulada.

Comment: @CandidMoe Gracias. Llevo ya un tiempo por aquí, mas o menos conozco las normas :-)

Comment: Cierto. Es un ejemplo que merece ser destacado y usado como guia.

Comment: No es para nada una respuesta: por qué usar C++ para interactuar con Python en vez de usar Cythton?

Comment: @Alfabravo Nunca he usado `python`, mas allá de algún *script* puntual. Mucho menos he programado un módulo para el. El módulo está en C++, y ha de ser usado desde un interprete *standard* de python bajo Windows. ¿ De que otra manera podría depurar mi código C++ y ver como interactua con python ?